# Opencv Object tracking and count objects which passes ROI in video frame

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on Opencv application that need to count any object which motion can be detected by the camera. The camera is still and I did the object tracking with opencv and cvblob by referring many tutorials.

I found some similar question:
[Object counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143577/opencv-multiply-objects-in-out-counting)

And i found this was similar
http://labs.globant.com/uncategorized/peopletracker-people-and-object-tracking/

I am new to OpenCV and I've gone through the opencv documentation but I couldn't find anything which is related to count moving objects in video.

Can any one please give me a idea how to do this specially the counting part. As I read in article above, they count people who crosses the virtual line.Is there a special algorithm to detect the object crossing the line?

Comment: Can you upload some example images or even a video?

Answer (score 5):

Your question might be to broad when you are asking about general technique that count moving objects in video sequences. I would give some hints that might help you:

- As usual in computer vision, there does not exist one specific way to solve your problem. Try do do some research about *people detection, background extraction* and *motion detection* to have a wider point of view
- State more clearly user requirements of your system, namely how many people can occur in the image frame? The things get complicated when you would like to track *more* than one person. Furthermore, can other moving objects appear on an image (e.g. animals)? If no and only one person are supposed to be track, the answer to your problem is pretty easy, see an explanation below. If yes, you will have to do more research.
- Usually you cannot find in OpenCV API direct solution to computer vision problem, namely there is not such method that solve directly problem of people counting. But for sure there exists some paper, reference (usually some scientific stuff) which can be adopted to solve your problem. So there is no method that "count people crossing vertical line". You have to solve problem my merging some algorithms together.

In the link you have provided one can see that they use some algorithm for background extraction which determined what is a non-moving background and moving foreground (in our case, a walking person). We are not sure if they use something more (or sophisticated), but information about background extraction is sufficient to start with problem solving.

And here is my contribution to the solution. Assuming only one person walks in front of the stable placed camera and no other objects motion can be observed, do as following:

1. Save frame when no person is moving in front of the camera, which will be used later as a reference for *background*
2. In a loop, apply some background detector to extract parts in the image representing motion ([MOG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractorMOG#backgroundsubtractormog) or even you can just calculate difference between background and current frame, followed by binary threshold and blob counting, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155005/backgound-extraction/17170690#17170690))
3. From the assumption, only one blob should be detected (if not, use some metrics the chooses "the best one". for example choose the one with maximum area). That blob is the person we would like to track. Knowing its position on an image, compare to the position of the "vertical line". Objects moving from left to right are exiting and from right to left entering.

Remember that this solution will only work in case of the assumption we stated.